# Python Django - {% request.user.is_authenticated %} in template tag not working with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am working on a comment/reply system in a blog. If there is any reply to the comment, it is shown as 1 reply etc. and clicking on the link will open the replies.

```
<a class="comment-reply-btn" href="#" > Reply </a>
```

clicking on reply toggles a div containing the replies, which otherwise is hidden using css.

The div is:-

```
<div class="comment-reply ml-5 mt-1">
{% for child_comment in comment.children %}
<img class="rounded-circle" alt="{{child_comment.user.get_full_name }}" src="{{child_comment.user.userprofile.get_user_image}}" height="18px" width="18px">
<h6 class="d-inline ml-3">{{ child_comment.user.get_full_name }}: </h6>
<span>{{ child_comment.content }}</span>
<footer>{{ child_comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago</footer>
{% endfor %}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form method="POST" action="."> {% csrf_token %}
{{ comment_form|crispy }}
<input type='hidden' name='parent_pk' value='{{ comment.pk }}'>
<input type='submit' value='Reply' class='btn btn-default'>
</form>
{% else %}
<p>You must login to reply</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

I am using the following css setting to hide the div from showing on page load :-

```
.comment-reply{
    display: none;
}
```

And the following js to open it up on clicking the reply button

```
$(".comment-reply-btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().next(".comment-reply").fadeToggle();
})
```

My problem is if I am logged in it opens up the replies and the form to write a new reply. But if I am not logged in, clicking the reply button doesn't open the replies (which it should).

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

you must handle this with js to what show for each case.
first define global variable for that in js:

```js
var user_is_authenticated = {{ request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false" }};
```

You can use the variable to handle the code. somthing like this:

```js
if (user_is_authenticated === true) {
    // append comments html code to your section
  }
else {
    // don't show the comments
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I am on the verge of solving my problem by using your answer. The problem now I am having is that I need to append a form which contains `{% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form|crispy }}`
which is being appended as 
`        " {% csrf_token %}        {{ comment_form|crispy }} " ` in html

Comment: you can get csrftoken from your browser cookie to fill value of hidden input of <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="" type="hidden"> and append it in your section you want.

Comment: I found the other way around. I added the form in a div and used remove instead of append to remove it if the user is not authenticated.